# Memory exhausted -- why?

Tags: kernel, memory, testing

I am running a console app with a large numerical calculation load. It has run successfully many times but at the moment it is crashing with 'memory exhausted' msg. Here are the two top snapshots that span the crash.

```
top - 19:22:32 up 10:33,  4 users,  load average: 1.05, 1.06, 1.05  
Tasks:   1 total,   1 running,   0 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie  
%Cpu(s):  8.3 us,  0.1 sy,  0.0 ni, 91.6 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st  
KiB Mem:  13195763+total, 97249256 used, 34708380 free,   137332 buffers  
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free.   973400 cached Mem
  
  PID ... USER ... PR ... NI ... VIRT ... RES ... SHR ... S ... %CPU ... %MEM ... TIME+ ...  COMMAND  
 3591 .. hexi ...... 20 .... 0 ... 92.976g  0.089t  18720 .. R ... 99.9 ........ 72.2 ...   614:50.72 . RobustPure+
  
top - 19:22:35 up 10:33,  4 users,  load average: 0.97, 1.05, 1.04  
Tasks:   0 total,   0 running,   0 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie  
%Cpu(s):  3.6 us,  1.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 95.2 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st  
KiB Mem:  13195763+total,  1827172 used, 13013046+free,   137332 buffers  
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free.   973400 cached Mem  
  
  PID ... USER ... PR ... NI ... VIRT ... RES ...  SHR ... S ... %CPU ... %MEM ... TIME+ ... COMMAND
```

In the first snap above everything looks hunky-dory, and more than 27 percent memory shows as available. But in less than three seconds the app has crashed, as seen in the second snap, in which the PID has disappeared. No alteration in number or state of processes occurred in between. The venue is Mint 17.3, with kernel 3.19. (I do not have the option of running on any other platform.) Below is the output from the ulimit -a command.

```
hexi@mint17 ~ $ ulimit -a  
core file size          (blocks, -c) ...0  
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) ...unlimited  
scheduling priority             (-e) ...0  
file size               (blocks, -f) ...unlimited  
pending signals                 (-i) ...515091  
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) ...64  
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) ...unlimited  
open files                      (-n) ...1024  
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) ...8  
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) ...819200  
real-time priority              (-r) ...0  
stack size              (kbytes, -s) ...8192  
cpu time               (seconds, -t) ...unlimited  
max user processes              (-u) ...515091  
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) ...unlimited  
file locks                      (-x) ...unlimited**
```

The memory has been tested with memtest86 and got a perfect goose egg. It is being run in default condition (no XMP). Can anyone tell me what is the likely cause of this crash event?

Some hardware details. The memory modules are four in number, 32 GB each.  Though free, top, and memtest86 can all see all the memory, is it possible that the kernel cannot allocate it for some reason?

I found question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30173133/linux-cannot-allocate-more-than-32-gb-64-gb-of-memory-in-a-single-process-due-t, which is applicable to the kernel I have, though not specifically to my problem. Using the test code contained there, I am able to test-allocate 124 GB of ram. Unless someone has some other good wisdom, I will assume that something in the method of memory allocation in the source is causing a blockage. I would still like to get some insight on this, if anyone has a comment.

Thanks for your attention.